# Apply CSS to a specific text in table header

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a dynamic html table which grows and shrinks based on certain parameters. I have to apply a certain styling to a column which has it's title as YTD.

Earlier when the table was static and I knew the position of the YTD column I was using the below css to style it

```
.DashboardTable tr td:nth-child(5) {
        background-color: #0091D5;
        color: white;
    }
```

Since I knew it is the 5th column that I have to style. But now that YTD column can move to 8 or 10 etc positions based on parameters.
So I was wondering if there is a way in css where I can target based on the column header(th) so instead of 5 it would say something like below and locate the th with text YTD and apply the style.

```
.DashboardTable tr td:nth-child("YTD") {
            background-color: #0091D5;
            color: white;
        }
```

Please let me know if this is possible

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can count from the back  `:nth-child(n - 2)` ?

Comment: :) Nice idea ..yeah it's static from the back.

Comment: Not working though..this is applying the style to the whole table

Comment: You will need javascript to do this - this snippet works but before I could post it the question was closed     var tableCells = document.querySelectorAll('.DashboardTable tr td')

    tableCells.forEach(function(tableCell){
    tableCell.innerHTML == 'YTD'
      ? tableCell.classList.add('highlight')
      : tableCell.classList.remove('highlight')
    })



<!-- language: lang-css -->

    td.highlight{
      background-color: #0091D5;
      color: white;
    }

Comment: :nth-last-child(2) this was it..Thanks for the help and ideas..really appreciate it.

Comment: No worries @user1221989